# Rails how to crud actions in admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, admin, crud

I would like to create my own admin interface from scratch (i tried rails_admin and active_admin last week) using Rails (3.2). My idea is to get the « show » action on localhost:3000/pages/1/, but to put all the crud actions in /admin (for example localhost:3000/admin/pages/1/edit or localhost:3000/admin/pages/new for example.

**This is what i have done :**

- `rails new website —skip-test-unit`
- `rails g scaffold page title:string content:string published:boolean`
- `rake db:migrate`

After i created a namespace call « admin » in `routes.rb` file :

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :pages
end
```

And an index view for the `/admin/pages/` with a second layout like this : 
**app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::PagesController < AdminController
  def index
  end
end
```

**app/views/admin/pages/index.html.erb**

```
(my html/css for /admin/pages index)
```

**app/controllers**

```
class AdminController extends < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
end
```

**Current result :**

- localhost:3000/pages => list all of my pages (with crud actions)
- localhost:3000/admin/pages => display the html/css of app/views/admin/pages/index.html.erb file

**Questions :**

1. Am i in the right way ?
2. Should i duplicate crud actions and views in /admin controller and view ?

I don’t know what i have to do right now .. Just need little help or new vision (if i'm in a wrong way). Thanx : )

Answer (score 4):

You should [look at this tutorial](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1) - you'll benefit from it a lot!

In essence, you *can* do what you're requesting (we have done it several times). You just have to create controllers in both the namespace & the "standard" routes, and route to both sets of controllers independently:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, only: [:show, :index]

namespace :admin do
    resources :pages, only: [:new, :edit, :create]
end
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer (and your link, i will read it tonight). So i have to move new/edit/create/update/destroy functions from app/pages_controller.rb to app/admin/pages_controller.rb ? (and I must do the same for views involved ?)